# Use of paddings and col in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Hello I want to make a similar div using bootstrap

[image]

what I did so far gave the following result:

[image]

I have problems with the main div should it be container or container fluid. Also, problems in the spaces between the different buttons, and most importantly the toggle, how to make it outside the div but aligned with it in the same row. here is the code of what I did so far using bootstrap 4.

```
    <style>
.container-fluid {
  background-color: #66BB6A;
  padding-top: 0.6%
}
.pagination a {
    margin: 0 4px; 
}
p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 5%;
}
</style>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#toggle-one').bootstrapToggle();
  })
</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="title col-sm-2">
      <p>Time selector Slider</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="pagination col-sm-4">
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1D</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1W</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1M</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1Q</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">YTD</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1Y</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">ALL</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
    </div>

    <input class="col-sm-2" id="toggle-one" checked type="checkbox">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class `pr-2` to the list items and the class `btn` to the link items.

The toggle needs to have its own div.

And whether you use the `.container` class or `.container-fluid` really depends on what you need. The latter is always full-width, even on the largest screens.

Here's a working code snippet (click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="container-fluid pt-1 bg-success">
    <div class="row py-2">
        <div class="title col-md-3">
            <p>Time selector Slider</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="pagination m-0 p-0 col-md-6">
            <li class="page-item pr-2"><a class="page-link btn" href="#">1D</a></li>
            <li class="page-item pr-2"><a class="page-link btn" href="#">1W</a></li>
            <li class="page-item pr-2"><a class="page-link btn" href="#">1M</a></li>
            <li class="page-item pr-2"><a class="page-link btn" href="#">1Q</a></li>
            <li class="page-item pr-2"><a class="page-link btn" href="#">YTD</a></li>
            <li class="page-item pr-2"><a class="page-link btn" href="#">1Y</a></li>
            <li class="page-item pr-2"><a class="page-link btn" href="#">ALL</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input id="toggle-one" checked type="checkbox">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For more info in regards to spacing (padding and margin classes) in Bootstrap 4, you should check out this page:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 0):

just add pr-(padding value) read the documentation for bootstrap 4.